# Adding single quotes and double quotes in an array using groovy

Tags: arrays, string, list, groovy

In groovy, I have an array as below.

```
def String=[Teacher 1, Teacher 2, Teacher 3]
```

How can we change this array to

```
 def String=['"Teacher 1"','"Teacher 2"','"Teacher 3"']
```

It would be great if you can help me with this.

Thanks a ton in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'll bite

Couple of things wrong in the question;

1. That's a List of Strings, not an array
2. Using class names as variable names is going to cause you issues

Anyway, back to the question...

Given the list:

```
def strings = ['Teacher 1', 'Teacher 2', 'Teacher 3']
```

You can wrap each of them in double quotes by using:

```
def quotedStrings = strings.collect { '"' + it + '"' }
```